# i have two columns in excel a and b. i want to merge both the columns into one column in the form of a1,b1,a2,b2 and so on

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I tried this formula in sheet

[image: in sheet]

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$5,QUOTIENT(ROW()+1,2),IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,2,1))
```

but it not works for me. only some rows are generated according to my requirement. I want the result like this...how can i do this..?

Answer (score 0):

you need to try with the below formula

```
=INDEX(A:B,QUOTIENT(ROW()+1,2),IF(MOD(ROW(),2)=0,2,1))
```